# javascript fat arrow in setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(alert('1'), 1000);
  setTimeout(() => alert('a'), 1000); // second setTimeout method
</script>
```

1) what is the meaing of "() =>" in the second setTimeout() statement?

Sometimes I see the () before the fat arrow => means the input argument and the statement after fat arrow => means the implementation, but for the above second setTimeout() method, seem the fat arrow is not this meaning, as setTimeout() really need two input parameter (callback function and delay time in milliseconds),

2) and in the above second setTimeout method, the statement after => is the input parameter of setTimeout(), not the implementation....

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining a function, that is calling other function: alert

same as:

```
setTimeout(function() { return alert('a') }, 1000)
```

Comment: ok, () => alert('a') is an anonymous function of the first parameter of setTimeout.

Answer (score 3):

Its syntactic sugar with also an different scope.

`() => {}`

Is equivalent to:

```
function(){

}
```

if you see an arrow function without `{}` that means the value right to it is gonna be returned:

`() => someVal`

Equivalent:

```
function(){
   return someVal;
}
```

In your case:

```
setTimeout(() => alert('a'), 1000);
```

The equivalent would be:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   return alert('a')
}, 1000);
```

Note: Arrow functions doesnt work on IE

Answer (score -1):

arrowFunction its a syntactic sugar for function(){....} so actually

```
() => {}
```

==

```
function() {
}
```

Comment: no. it's not just syntactic sugar since it has different scoping.

Comment: @GottZ the scoping is the same, the context isn't.

Comment: @VLAZ technically the scope is the surrounding lexical enclosing environment. https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-namedevaluation